# Saving to a realtime firebase using android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am saving user information to a realtime database on a android studio app. When the user goes to register they select weather they are a PT or client by using radio buttons. As shown in my database all the user information is being saved under the user child node on firebase. Is there a way I can create subheadings called PT and Clients underneath user in the realtime database by using the radio buttons. Sign up code is:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   EditText txt_fullname, txt_email, txt_mobilenumber, txt_repassword, txt_password;
   Button btn_register;
   RadioButton radioJobClient, radioJobPT;
   DatabaseReference databaseReference;
   FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
   String job ="";
   FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    txt_fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_fullname);
    txt_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_UserEmail);
    txt_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Password);
    txt_repassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_rePassword);
    txt_mobilenumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobilenumber);
    btn_register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_reg);
    radioJobClient = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_Client);
    radioJobPT = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_PersonalTrainer);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");
   // new code

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String  fullname = txt_fullname.getText().toString();
            final String  email = txt_email.getText().toString();
            final String  mobilenumber = txt_mobilenumber.getText().toString();
            final String  password = txt_password.getText().toString();
            final String rePassword = txt_repassword.getText().toString();
            if (radioJobClient.isChecked()){
                 job = "Client";
            }
            if (radioJobPT.isChecked()){
                job = "PT";
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Please enter Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(fullname)){
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Please enter fullname", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                User user = new User(
                                        fullname,
                                        email,
                                        mobilenumber,
                                        password,
                                        job
                                );


                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User")
                                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                        .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));


                                    }
                                });

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }

                            // ...
                        }
                    });




        }
    });
```

}

[image: database structure]

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (radioJobClient.isChecked()){
                     job = "Client";
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(job).child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));


                                        }
                                    });
                }
                if (radioJobPT.isChecked()){
                    job = "PT";
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(job).child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
```